# Syntax using Dlookup in a loop with strings and dates

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to get a command working to lookup if objects have been already selected for certain dates. I would like to do this with the `Dlookup` method, problem is, I am still getting used to SQL syntax. This is the code I am trying to get working:

```
    Dim i, coun as Integer
        For i = 1 to 10
             If IsNull(DLookup("[Column1]", "Table1", "[Column1] LIKE '*AT 1/*' & i  " 
              And (("[Date_Beg] BETWEEN #" & Me.txtDate1 & "#" AND "#" & Me.txtDate2 & "#") 
                  Or ("[Date_End] BETWEEN #" & Me.txtDate1 & "#" AND "#" & Me.txtDAte2 & "#")))) = True Then
             coun = coun
        else
             coun = coun + 1
        End If
```

When it gets executed, I get an error

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

***EDIT***: Please go see my answer to see the code that ended up working for me.

Comment: You may also have to apply explicit formatting of the the date values: `"[Date_Beg] ]Between #" & Format(Me!txtDate1, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And ..."`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the SQL string you are trying to pass into the `DLookup` function.  When you need SQL strings like this I find it best to store them as variable and then pass the variable into the function.  Let me know if this works for you.

```
Sub QueryExample()

    Dim i, coun As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    For i = 1 To 10
         strSQL = "[Column1] LIKE *AT 1/*" & i
         strSQL = strSQL & " And (([Date_Beg] BETWEEN #" & Me.txtDate1 & "# AND #" & Me.txtDAte2 & "#)"
         strSQL = strSQL & " Or ([Date_End] BETWEEN #" & Me.txtDate1 & "# AND #" & Me.txtDAte2 & "#))"
         'Debug.Print strSQL

         If IsNull(DLookup("[Column1]", "Table1", strSQL)) = True Then
             coun = coun
         Else
             coun = coun + 1
         End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I updated my answer.  Thanks for catching that

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. When I try to run this, I get a ```Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression```

Comment: in the first strSQL line, should it not be ```LIKE *AT 1/" & i & "*"``` to include the ```i```?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the suggestion from @pheeper and modifying his code a little bit I got the program working. This is what worked:

```
Dim i, coun as Integer     
For i = 1 To 10
       strSQL = "[Column1] LIKE ""*AT 1/" & i & "*"""
       strSQL = strSQL & " And (([Date_Beg] BETWEEN #" & Me.txtDate1 & "# AND #" & Me.txtDate2 & "#)"
       strSQL = strSQL & " Or ([Date_End] BETWEEN #" & Me.txtDate1 & "# AND #" & Me.txtDate2 & "#))"
       'Debug.Print strSQL
    
       If IsNull(DLookup("[Column1]", "Table1", strSQL)) = True Then
           coun = coun
       Else
           coun = coun + 1
       End If
Next i
```